# GET "link" net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Написал плагин для wordpress, в котором подключаю скрипты.

```
    wp_enqueue_script('drawing', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/japanese-candlestick-chart' . '/script.js');
```

**Вижу ошибку только при активации плагина.**

Сама ошибка

```
GET http://golda/var/www/golda/wp-content/plugins/japanese-candlestick-chart/script.js?ver=5.9.2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

полный код -

````
``` if(!defined('ABSPATH')){ //Защита от злоумышлинников
     die; 
 }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jcc_graph');

function jcc_graph() {
    wp_enqueue_script('drawing', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/japanese-candlestick-chart' . '/script.js');
}```
````

По идее, путь указан верно - скрин[image: Расположение файла]

Comment: Посмотри внимательно в адрес ошибки. А потом сравни свою функцию с документацией https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script. Почитай что возвращает WP_PLUGIN_DIR

Comment: Нужно заменить WP_PLUGIN_DIR на WP_PLUGIN_URL